# Wordpress. Откуда берется зачеркивание у картинки-ссылки . Не могу найти в CSS этот код

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Вставляю когда просто картинку, этого зачеркивания нет, когда назначаю ссылку, появляется зачеркивание.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С включённым pagespeed module вы вряд ли что найдёте. Выключите его, тогда можно будет попробовать посмотреть.

Comment: такого плагина не устанавливал, возможно ли, что вы говорите о услуге ускорителя сайта, который мы используем на хостинге? 
 вот такие услуги активированы
page cash
css ускоритель (первичная загрузка, кэширование, вынос в отдельные папки)

Comment: Есть возможность загрузить проект на временный хост для тестирования?

Comment: Да, это не плагин, а модуль на хостинге. Отключайте все эти услуги, пока не пропадёт pagespeed.CheckCriticalImage... и файлы css не перестанут быть сжатыми.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Модуль Pagespeed можно отключить извне, добавив `?ModPagespeed=off` к url страницы. (Совсем забыл об этом, а ведь у меня есть плагин, который предоставляет такое отключение для отладки на всех страницах сайта: [PageSpeed Module](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/kagg-pagespeed-module/)).

Я отключил Pagespeed в своём браузере и посмотрел, в чём дело:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это ваша тема Кактус так цветёт :). Она добавляет border-bottom ко всем ссылкам в виджетах футера. Задайте вашим ссылкам для соцсетей какой-нибудь свой класс и поправьте в нём border-bottom. Или, поскольку у вас всего два textwidget, сделайте так:

```
.widget-box .textwidget a {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо задавить border-bottom в классе .widget-box a. Он встречается в двух файлах.

[image: Inspector]